# Magento 2.2.4 - How to move Layered Navigation on top of Content on Search Pages

Tags: layout, magento2.2, search

I am using the below mentioned code to move the Layered navigation above content on Search pages in catalogsearch_result_index.xml

```
<body>
    <move element="catalogsearch.leftnav" destination="content" before="-" />
</body>
```

But it is not showing above content on search pages.

Please help me in correcting the code, if i am missing something in this

Comment: can you elaborate your code

Comment: You can try This 

<move element="catalogsearch.leftnav" destination="header.container" />

Comment: Not working:( this is the code, i have overwrite this file (/app/design/frontend/Vendor_Theme/base/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml ) in my theme for getting this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `<move element="sidebar.main" destination="content" before="-"/>`
The layered navigation for the search results page is defined in `/vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml` and the referenceContainer is `sidebar.main` not `catalogsearch.leftnav`.

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this, for v2.4.5 this will break the search toolbar sorter.